# my app doesn't asks permission at the time of downloading from google play store.I have specified location permission in my manifest file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

Mainifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/hero3"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="info.food360.nikhil.splash"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="info.food360.nikhil.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity
        android:name="info.food360.nikhil.DesActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="DestinationActivity" />
    <activity android:name="info.food360.nikhil.Suggestion" />
    <activity android:name="info.food360.nikhil.LocationWork" />
    <activity android:name="info.food360.nikhil.logicBehind"></activity>
</application>
```

my app need location permission I thought google play store would ask at the time of downloading but user have to set location manually.what is the way that google play store should ask what should I add in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running in the android API version 23 or higher you'll need to require permissions at [runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting). To ask for permissions you should do it right before using the feature that uses the permission:

```
int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 123;
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //app doesn't have permission yet

     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
} else {
    // Permission has already been granted
}
```

Then override the onRequestPermissionsResult to see if the user has given the permission:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted
            } else {
                // permission denied
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is -->  MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION

Comment: sorry, it's a simple int variable

Comment: sorry didn't understand how should I use this variable? I have pasted the code given by you in my onCreate method. First error was this-MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION

Comment: you need to declare it outside onCreate, i've edited the answer so you can see :)

Comment: can you tell me how to enable gps location also using runtime permission?

Comment: in this part of the code new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, you can add every permission you'd like to ask because this is an array :)